# Android Firebase notification "OnTokenRefresh" not getting called

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on a project in which Firebase notification is being used. I am facing an issue of not receiving notification after some hours of application installation. Initially notifications are received as expected but later not working as intended.

I am unable to identify the cause of this issue.

```
@Override  public void onTokenRefresh()
```

above method is used inside a service class (FCMIDService) for token refresh of firebase and using the latest token for future use of notification.

`<service android:name=".services.fcm.FCMIDService"><intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/></intent-filter>
</service>`

Any help should be greately appreciated.

Comment: is this package name correct ".services.fcm.FCMIDService" ?

Comment: your question title does not match your question details. In title you say that `“OnTokenRefresh” not getting called`, and in question - that you don't receive notifications.

Comment: @ Vlad Matvienko  "OnTokenRefresh" is related to notifications. Question Title must be short and precise. If you find no relation between them can u define it in more detail.

Answer (score 3):

**onTokenRefresh** in FirebaseInstanceIdService is only called when a new token is generated. If your app was previously installed and generated a token then onTokenRefresh would not be called. Try uninstalling and reinstalling the app to force the generation of a new token, this would cause onTokenRefresh to be called.

make sure that t your FirebaseInstanceIdService is properly defined in your AndroidManifest.xml like this

```
<service
    android:name="com.bnt.etailers.fcm.MyFireBaseInstanceIDService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<service
    android:name="com.bnt.etailers.fcm.GCMNotificationIntentService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Hi @ Nilesh Rathod  I am using as above. Without uninstalling app how can I reproduce onTokenRefresh or is there any scenarios in which this method will get called.

Comment: @RaghulSugathan call InstanceID of the playservice by InstanceID.getInstance(this).deleteInstanceID() and call it from background thread, after u successfully delete it, call InstanceID.getInstance(this).getID() to generate new token

Comment: @RaghulSugathan If you would like to manually force the onTokenRefresh(), you can create an IntentService and delete the token instance. Then, when you call getToken, the onTokenRefresh() method will be called again

Comment: I will look into it Nilesh Rathod. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @ Nilesh Rathod. It will be useful for me to refer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146390/discussion-between-nilesh-rathod-and-raghul-sugathan).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your Home Activity to get the latest token every time when the app restarts.

```
String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
```